# Не работает TMemIniFile.SetStrings

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, ini

```
var
  M: TStringStream;
  ini: TMemIniFile;
  sl: TStringList;
  s: string;
begin
   M := TStringStream.Create();
   M.Position := 0;
   IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
   IdHTTP1.GEt('http://******.ini', M);

   showmessage(M.DataString); //выводит корректное содержимое ini

   sl := TStringList.Create;
   sl.Text := M.DataString;
   ini := TMemIniFile.Create('');
     try
       ini.SetStrings(sl);
       s := ini.ReadString('section1','param1','error');

       showmessage(s); //выводит error, хотя секция и параметр есть !!!
     finally
      sl.free;
      ini.Free;
      M.Free;
     end;
```

---

```
    [section1]
    param1=Иванов Иван Иванович
    param2=ул.Ленина
    [section2]
    param1=Петр Петрович
    param2=ул.Советская
```

Comment: ну добавьте в вопрос содержимое `sl`

Comment: всмысле? в sl передается содержание ini файла полученного в M.Datastring.

Comment: хорошо, хорошо, я Вам верю. Содержание, наверное, секретное?

Comment: добавил содержимое

Comment: вы ведь при дебаге взяли значение `sl.text`, а не просто скопировали строки из файла, да?

Comment: это имеет значение? намекаете на кодировку? или что?

Comment: если вы хотите найти часть программы, где ошибка, то, очевидно, имеет. приведите содержимое `sl.text` на момент вызова `ini.SetStrings(sl);`

Comment: Продебажил
'[section1]'#012'param1=Иванов Иван Иванович', ' ' <repeats 107 times>, '*'#012'param2=ул.Ленина'<repeats 13 times>,

Comment: '#012'[section2]'#012'param1=Петр Петрович'#012'param2=ул.Советская'

Comment: Всё тоже самое если делать с реальным этим же файлом, скачанным и сохраненным в каталог, то всё нормльно.